# Order SQL results by number of LIKE matches from multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, sql-like

```
SELECT id 
FROM table 
WHERE fistname LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') 
   OR secondname LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') 
   OR middlename LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')");

$stmt->bind_param("sss", $first, $second, $middle);
```

I would like to be able to sort the returned results so that they will appear in order of the total number of matches.

For example:

```
  id | firstname |  secondname   |  middlename    
------------------------------------------------    
  1  |  Thomas   | Smith       |   John    
  2  |  Bob      | Smith       |   John
```

For vars $first = "Thomas", $second = "Smith", $middle="John", the results would be sorted in the order 1,2

For vars $first = "Bob", $second = "Smith", $middle="Peter", the results would be sorted in the order 2,1

etc...

Thanks!

Comment: Making a [FULLTEXT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html) index and use [Boolean Full-Text Searches](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html) instead would make more sense as you can do `SELECT ... ORDER BY AGAINST ('...' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` to get relevancy ordering as `LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')` can never be optimized.

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY
       CASE WHEN firstname  LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
       CASE WHEN secondname LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
       CASE WHEN middlename LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

In Mysql a Boolean expression like: `name like '%bob%'` is evaluated as `1`(`true`) or `0`(`false`), so you can add all the `like` expressions:

```
order by
  (fistname like concat('%', ?, '%')) +
  (secondname like concat('%', ?, '%')) +
  (middlename like concat('%', ?, '%')) desc
```

But since you don't want to repeat the parameters in the `WHERE` clause and in `ORDER BY`, you can write it like this:

```
SELECT t.* FROM (
  SELECT *,
    (fistname LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')) +
    (secondname LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')) +
    (middlename LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')) as matches 
  FROM table
) as t 
WHERE t.matches > 0
ORDER BY t.matches DESC
```